# Reset password on sorcery isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sorcery

I'm trying to implement sorcery gem for user registration and can't understand why I get an error associated with reset password.

I'm following this guide https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/Reset-password

*Error:*

```
To use reset_password submodule, you must define a mailer (config.reset_password_mailer = YourMailerClass).
```

*# config/initializers/sorcery.rb*

```
  Rails.application.config.sorcery.configure do |config|
    config.user_config do |user|
      user.reset_password_mailer = UserMailer
    end
  end
```

*user_mailer.rb*

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def reset_password_email(user)
    @user = User.find user.id
    @url  = edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_password_token)
    mail(:to => user.email,
         :subject => "Your password has been reset")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already restarted your rails server?
If you change anything into initializers, you need to restart rails server.

Comment: Yes, after I had changed sorcery.rb, I restarted server.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment line in initializer `sorcery.rb`:

```
user.reset_password_email_method_name = :reset_password_email
```

Add check documentation:
https://github.com/Sorcery/sorcery/wiki/Reset-password